# Set of Distributions on Finite Set with Monotone Likelihood Ratio Order forms a Complete Lattice?

Tags: probability-distributions, order-theory, lattice-orders

Let $(X,\geq)$ be a finite, linearly ordered set, and $\Delta(X)$ the set of distributions over $X$, that is, $p \in \Delta(X) \Longrightarrow p:X \to [0,1]$ such that $\sum_{x \in X}p(x)=1$.

For $p,q\in \Delta(X)$, $p$ is said to monotone-likelihood-ratio-dominate $q$, denoted $p\geq_{MLRP} q$ iff $\forall x'>x$, $p(x')q(x)\geq q(x')p(x)$.

- **Is $(\Delta(X),\geq_{MLRP})$ a lattice? Is it a complete lattice?**

A reference would also be very welcome.

---

For clarification: $(\Delta(X),\geq_{MLRP})$ is a partially ordered set, since:
(1) [Reflexive] $p \geq_{MLRP} p$ as $p(x')p(x)=p(x')p(x)$;
(2) [Antisymmetric] $p \geq_{MLRP} q \geq_{MLRP} p \Longrightarrow p=q$.

> $p \geq_{MLRP} q \geq_{MLRP} p$ implies $p(x')q(x)= p(x)q(x') \forall x,x'$. Let $\tilde X=
> > \text{support}(p)\cup \text{support}(q)$ and  let $x_n$ denote the
> $n$th smallest element of $\tilde X$ according to $\geq$.
> Then $\sum_{x\geq x_1}p(x)q(x_1)=q(x_1)=p(x_1)=\sum_{x\geq
>  x_1}q(x)p(x_1)$. For arbitrary $n>1$, assume that $p(x_m)=q(x_m)$ for
> all $m<n$. Then $p(x_n)\sum_{x< x_n}q(x)=q(x_n)\sum_{x< x_n}p(x)$.
> Since $p(x_1)=q(x_1)>0$ and $x_n>x_1$, $\sum_{x< x_n}q(x)=\sum_{x<
> > x_n}p(x)>0$, and then $p(x_n)=q(x_n)$, and, by induction, $p=q$.

(3) [Transitive] $p \geq_{MLRP} q \geq_{MLRP} r \Longrightarrow p \geq_{MLRP} r$.

> Supposing otherwise implies $\exists x'>x$ s.t. and $r(x')p(x)>
> > p(x')r(x)$.   $p(x')r(x)<r(x')p(x) \Longrightarrow r(x'),p(x)>0$.
>
> Suppose $q(x)+q(x')>0$.  Then  $q(x')\frac{r(x)}{r(x')}\geq q(x)$ and
> $q(x)\frac{p(x')}{p(x)}\geq q(x')$,  which in turn implies
> $q(x)\frac{p(x')r(x)}{r(x')p(x)}\geq q(x)$, and so $q(x)=q(x')=0$, a
> contradiction.
>
> This implies that for any $x'>x$ such that $q(x)+q(x')>0$,
> $p(x')r(x)\geq r(x')p(x)$.
>
> Now suppose that for $x'>x$, $p(x')r(x)< r(x')p(x)$, and so
> $q(x)=q(x')=0$.  Since $0=q(x')r(y)\geq r(x')q(y)$ $\forall y<x'$ and
> $r(x')>0$, then $q(y)=0, \forall y\leq x'$.
>
> Let $x'':=\min\{y\in X| q(y)>0\} \Longrightarrow x''>x'$. $\forall
> > z\geq x''$, $p(z)q(x'')\geq q(z)p(x'') \Longrightarrow \sum_{z\geq
> > x''}p(z)q(x'')\geq p(x'') \Longrightarrow q(x'')>p(x'')\geq 0$.
> Moreover,  $\forall z\leq x''$, $p(x'')q(z)\geq q(x'')p(z)
> > \Longrightarrow p(x'')q(x'')\geq q(x'')\sum_{z\leq x''}p(z)
> > \Longrightarrow p(x'')\geq \sum_{z\leq x''}p(z) \Longrightarrow p(z)=0
> > \forall z<x'' \Longrightarrow p(x)=0$, a contradiction.

What the question is asking is:
(a) if $p\wedge q:=\sup\{r\in \Delta(X)| p\geq_{MLRP} r, q\geq_{MLRP} r\}$ and $p\vee q:=\inf\{r\in \Delta(X)| r\geq_{MLRP} p, r\geq_{MLRP} q\}$ exist; i.e. if meets, $p\wedge q$, and joins, $p \vee q$, are well-defined distributions; and
(b) if, for any $S \subseteq \Delta(X)$,
$\wedge S:=\sup\{r\in \Delta(X)| p\geq_{MLRP} r, \forall p \in S\}$ and
$\vee S:=\inf\{r\in \Delta(X)| r\geq_{MLRP} p, \forall p \in S\}$ exist.

Comment: I think you should edit your post to clarify what you mean with distributions. For people who work with probability and statistics that must be clear enough. For many people from order and lattices, perhaps not. I assume you mean that $p \in \Delta(X)$ iff $p:X\to[0,1]$ is such that $$\sum_{x\in X}p(x)=1.$$ Is it so? Also did you even prove that the relation is a partial order relation?

Comment: @amrsa Yes, I did prove $(\Delta(X), \geq_{MLRP})$ is a poset. I left the proof above for reference. I doubt that people who work on order theory don't know this though.

Comment: For future reference: if $L$ is the set of logconcave distributions with full support on $X$, then indeed $(L,\geq_{MLRP})$ is a lattice. If you restrict $L$ to be the set of logconcave distributions satisfying $p(x)\geq \delta>0$, then $(L,\geq_{MLRP})$ is a complete lattice.

Comment: So did you solve it? If yes, I don't you answer your own question?

Comment: I also had concluded that if $p(x)>0$ for all $x$ then the result is easy, since then $q\leq p$ iff $$\frac{q(y)}{q(x)}\leq\frac{p(y)}{p(x)},$$ whenever $x\leq y$. When some take $0$ value, things can get more complicated, and I'm not certain that I could work all the cases out. When you say that restricting to $p(x)\geq\delta>0$ gives a complete lattice, I think you should still consider the top ($\top$) and bottom ($\bot$) cases, where $X=\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$, with $$x_1<\cdots<x_n$$ and $\bot(x_1)=\top(x_n)=1$ (all others being $0$, of course), and these don't satisfy the requirement.